# Pandas DataFrame cast multiple types to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to declare different types for the columns of a pandas DataFrame at instantiation:

```
frame = pandas.DataFrame({..some data..},dtype=[str,int,int])
```

This works if dtype is only one type (e.g `dtype=float`), but not multiple types as above - is there a way to do this?

The common solution seems to be to cast later:

```
frame['some column'] = frame['some column'].astype(float)
```

but this has a couple of issues:

1. It's messy
2. Looks like it involves an unnecessary copy operation - this could be expensive on large data sets.

Comment: in general the types will be correct inferred on creation (or as show below you can explicity create a series/ndarray to that effect)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative, you can specify the `dtype` for each column by creating the `Series` objects first.

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': pd.Series(['1.0', '2.0', '3.0'], dtype=float), 'y': pd.Series(['1', '2', '3'], dtype=int)})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   x  y
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
x    float64
y      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also create a NumPy array with specific dtypes and then convert it to DataFrame.

```
data = np.zeros((2,),dtype=[('A', 'i4'),('B', 'f4'),('C', 'a10')])
data[:] = [(1,2.,'Hello'),(2,3.,"World")]
DataFrame(data)
```

See [From structured or record array](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-structured-or-record-array)