# pandas DataFrame shows ints as floats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pandas DataFrame shows ints as floats.
But I would like to show those ints as ints.

```
X_train = train.iloc[:, 1:].values.astype('float32')
y_train = train.iloc[:, 0].values.astype('uint8')
X = test.values.astype('float32')
```

So, the dtypes are 'float32', 'unit8' and 'float32'.

Show min and max values for X_train, y_train and X in a DataFrame (in Jupyter Notebook).

```
pd.DataFrame([[np.amin(X_train), np.amax(X_train)], 
              [np.amin(y_train), np.amax(y_train)], 
              [np.amin(X), np.amax(X)]], 
             columns = ['min', 'max'], 
             index = ['X_train', 'y_train', 'X'])
```

Output:

```
        min max
X_train 0.0 255.0
y_train 0.0 9.0
X       0.0 255.0
```

But I would expect:

```
        min max
X_train 0.0 255.0
y_train 0   9
X       0.0 255.0
```

But...

```
print(np.amax(y_train))
```

Outputs to 9 (not 9.0)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Columns cannot have mixed data-types, unless you use `dtype=object` for the whole column, in which case you might as well not even use `pandas`. So, `pandas` (or probably the underlying `numpy` array) has used type promotion to `float32`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` types things by columns.  So each column will have a specific `dtype`.  It determines that up-casting the `int` is better so that the entire column can be `float` rather than keeping the column as dtype `object`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0., 255.],
    [0, 9],
    [0., 255.]
])

df

     0      1
0  0.0  255.0
1  0.0    9.0
2  0.0  255.0
```

---

```
df.dtypes

0    float64
1    float64
dtype: object
```

---

Use `dtype=object` to retain the individual types.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0., 255.],
    [0, 9],
    [0., 255.]
], dtype=object)

df

   0    1
0  0  255
1  0    9
2  0  255
```

---

```
df.dtypes

0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

---

```
df.applymap(type)

                 0                1
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
1    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>
2  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
```

---

I'd only use this for reporting purposes.  If you want to use this for further calculations, you lose many efficiencies.  I'd spend time rearranging your data.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, each column in a DataFrame has it's own dtype. After swapping rows and columns it gives the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataFrame` by default consists of a 2D array of elements that are all the same type, because it is backed by a NumPy 2D array. In this case, some of your values are floats so it chooses a floating-point type. If you want to have rows of different types, you'll need to add them as separate series. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000207) for more information.