# Why is DataFrame int column value sometimes returned as float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I add a calculated column `c` to a DataFrame that only contains integers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(*[np.random.randint(1,3,5), np.random.random(5)])), columns=['a', 'b'])
df['c'] = np.ceil(df.a/df.b).astype(int)
df.dtypes
```

The DataFrame reports that the column type of `c` is indeed `int`:

```
a      int64
b    float64
c      int32
dtype: object
```

If I access a value from `c` like this then I get an int:

```
df.c.values[0]        # Returns "3"
type(df.c.values[0])  # Returns "numpy.int32"
```

But if I access the same value using `loc` I get a float:

```
df.iloc[0].c        # Returns "3.0"
type(df.iloc[0].c)  # Returns "numpy.float64"
```

Why is this?

I would like to be able to access the value using indexes without having to cast it (again) to an int.

Comment: [Informative answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45445233/2662901).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what's happening is when you are accessing `df.iloc[0].c`, you have to first access `df.iloc[0]` which includes all three columns. `df.iloc[0]` then casts to the type that represents all three columns, which is `numpy.float64`.

Interestingly enough, I can avoid this by adding a string column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(*[np.random.randint(1,3,5), np.random.random(5)])), columns=['a', 'b'])
df['c'] = np.ceil(df.a/df.b).astype(int)
df['d'] = ['hi', 'bye', 'hello', 'cya', 'sup']


print(df.iloc[0].c)
print(type(df.iloc[0].c))

print(df.dtypes)
```

To your end question, you can avoid this whole mess by using `df.loc[0, 'c']` instead of `iloc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(*[np.random.randint(1,3,5), np.random.random(5)])), columns=['a', 'b'])
df['c'] = np.ceil(df.a/df.b).astype(int)

print(df.loc[0, 'c'])

print(df.loc[0, 'c'].dtype)
```

```
15
int32
```

Comment: I just tested your last suggestion on my original example and it does not work!  I get the value `c` as float.  Did you test it?

Comment: Just re-tested it, it works for me. I've added it as an edit.

Comment: This is getting weird: Use a DataFrame with a date index like this and it doesn't work:  `df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(*[np.random.randint(1,3,5), np.random.random(5)])), index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-05').tolist(), columns=['a', 'b'])` ...
`df['c'] = np.ceil(df.a/df.b).astype(int)` ... 
`df.loc['20200101', 'c']` ... >> `3.0`

Comment: Not quite sure why it does that, but using a datetime object for the index fixes that issue.  Both `df.loc[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1), 'c']` and `df.loc[numpy.datetime64('2020-01-01'), 'c']` worked for me.

Comment: Too weird – I posted this as a [separate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75224332/2662901).

Answer (score 0):

- When I execute your code, result is this dataframe:

```
df
   a         b   c
0  1  0.315388   4
1  1  0.111275   9
2  1  0.251253   4
3  2  0.043162  47
4  1  0.047985  21
```

- When I type in the interpreter `df['c'].values` I get this:
  `array([ 4,  9,  4, 47, 21])`. It's to say all the c-column values.
- When I type in the interpreter `df.iloc[0]` I get the dataframe's first row values:

```
a    1.000000
b    0.315388
c    4.000000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

**What we could notice**

All c-column values are integers while all first row values are not of the same types because we have two integers and a float value.
This fact is very important.

Indeed by definition an array is `a collection of elements of the same type`.

So to represent a float in a collection of values that are integers, conversion must be to float for all elements to respect this rule, because floats can contain integers but the reverse is not true.

**Conclusion**

Type of a collection of integers is `int...`

Type of a collection of floats is `float...`

Type of a collection of integers containing at least one float is converted to `float...`

**Quote**

*"An array is a concept that stores different items of the same type together as one and makes calculating the stance of each element easier by adding an offset to the base number." (codeinstitute.net)*

**To check this and go further**

```py
# case A : value 2 is an integer
mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df.iloc[0]
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64

# case B : value '2' is a string
mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3, 'd': 4},]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df.iloc[0]
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

In the case A all elements are integers so dtype remains `int...`.

Like in the case B collection contains a string that can't be a `float...`, all elements are converted to `object` type.