# Why does indexing DataFrame by date string affect column return type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While investigating [why int columns are sometimes returned as floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75178105/2662901) we found the following surprising behavior:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(*[np.random.randint(1,3,5), np.random.random(5)])), index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-05').tolist(), columns=['a', 'b'])
df['c'] = np.ceil(df.a/df.b).astype(int)
df.loc['20200101', 'c']  # << Returns value as float
df.loc[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1), 'c']  # << Returns value as int
```

Why does using the index value `"20200101"` cause the `c` value to be returned as a `float` (even though the column is of type `int`) but using the index value `datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)` causes it to be returned as an `int`?

Comment: What's your python and pandas versions?

Comment: @jlandercy Python 3.9.2, pandas 1.2.0

Comment: Can't reproduce here: https://ideone.com/K1w5g2

Answer (score 0):

When I do

```
print(type(df.loc['20200101', 'c']))
print(type(df.loc[datetime.datetime(2020,1,1), 'c']))
```

I get

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I'm using Python 3.9.7 on Visual Studio Code Insiders 1.75.0

Comment: Not me: The second expression returns `<class 'numpy.int32'>`.  I'm using Python 3.9.2

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: @jlandercy pandas 1.3.4

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. An answer should explain how to solve the OP's problem, not just say that the problem doesn't exist.